# Arduino pro micro not recognized, how to fix with no reset button?

Tags: arduino, usb, driver, arduino-ide

I loaded a program to blink an LED on my Arduino Micro board using the Arduino IDE. It worked.

Then I selected another type of Arduino board from Tools > Board, and I started getting the message "USB device not recognized" whenever I reloaded the code, even after going back to selecting "Arduino Micro".

The issue is not with the USB cable. I uninstalled the device from the USBC (from Device Manager). Nothing has worked so far. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: The reset button only resets the current code. It doesn't reflash the microcontroller. The reset pin is probably exposed on the header though so you could interface it through there. If you would add more information about your board we could help more

Comment: [Here](https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07DF5CPTB/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) is the link to the board I am using.

Comment: well there is a reset pin called `RST` on your board and you can reset it by pulling it to `GND` [ref](https://programmingelectronics.com/how-to-use-an-external-reset-button-with-arduino/)